# Why can't I comment on this question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I recently saw [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13717/3170) and went to comment, only to find that there was no link to add a comment. See screenshot below:

[image: example showing that I can't comment]

This problem does not show up on other questions. I can't get to a computer to see how it works on desktop. Is the question protected in some way that blocks me from commenting, or is it a bug in the mobile app?

Edit: the mobile and desktop websites both say "comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews," which doesn't make sense because it doesn't show up as deleted or locked.

Answer (score 3):

At first, I didn't see on the mobile and desktop sites that the migration was rejected, and thus I guess the post was technically "locked." The mobile app doesn't say anything about this, which is why I get confused.

I'll probably file a feature request to somehow show when the post is both locked and on-hold.

Comment: Yup - Rejected migrations are locked (technically it should have *deleted* it too - I'm not sure why it didn't but I've taken care of that).